# referenced binding param not triggering animation

Tags: swiftui

I have a custom view

```
struct CustomView: View {

  @Binding var text: String
  ...

var body: some View {
  VStack {
    ...
    Text(SomeText)
      .offset(y: text.isEmpty ? 0 : -25)
      .scaleEffect(text.isEmpty ? 1 : 0.5, anchor: .leading)
      .animation(.spring(), value: text.isEmpty)

    ...
  }
```

the scale effect and offset animation never trigger if text is referenced from an object.

For example, I have a ViewModel such as

```
class SomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var text: String = ""
}
```

And the parent View such as

```
struct ParentView: View {
  @State private var vm = SomeViewModel()
  
  @State private var text = "" //this one works!
   ...
  
   var body: some View {
     ...
     CustomView(..., text: $vm.text) // no animation, but the value of v.name is updated
     CustomView(..., text: $text)) // everything works, including animation
```

Comment: Change SomeViewModel to struct and usually we name it ParentViewConfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SwiftUI to properly update based on changes of an `ObservableObject`, you will need to use a different property wrapper. Usually this is either `@ObservedObject` or `@StateObject` dependent on the context you are using it in.

Try using `@StateObject` if this is where you are first initialising the class.

[StateObject Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject)